# validar campo dinamico com validate

Tags: jquery, jquery.validate

estou tentando fazer uma validação para um campo dinâmico com validate, mais ele só valida uma vez.Os campos adicionado dinamicamente não estão sendo  validados segue abaixo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".data").mask("99/99/9999");

  var i = 1;
  $('a#adicionar').click(function() {
    i++;

    $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row' + i + '"><td>Inicio:</td><td><input name="inicio[]" id="inicio' + i + '" type="text" value="" class="form-control data" /></td><td>Término:</td><td><input name="termino[]" id="termino' + i + '"type="text" value="" class="form-control data" /></td><td><a name="remove" id="' + i + '" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove"><i class="fa fa-times-circle">-</i></a></td></tr>');
    $(".data").mask("99/99/9999");
    $("#inicio" + i + "").focus();

  });

  $(document).on('click', 'a.btn_remove', function() {
    var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
    $('#row' + button_id + '').remove();
  });

  $("#teste").validate({

    rules: {

      'inicio[]': {
        required: true,
      date: true

      },
      'termino[]': {
        required: true,
      date: true

      }
    },
    messages: {
      'inicio[]': "* Informe uma data",
      'termino[]': "* Informe uma data",

    },
    highlight: function(element) {
      $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error')
      $(element).parent().find('.form-control-feedback').removeClass('glyphicon-ok').addClass('glyphicon-remove');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
      $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
      $(element).parent().find('.form-control-feedback').removeClass('glyphicon-remove').addClass('glyphicon-ok');
    },
    //errorElement: 'span',
    errorClass: 'help-block',
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      if (element.parent('.input-group').length) {
        error.insertAfter(element.parent());
      } else {
        error.insertAfter(element);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>
<form id="teste">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <table class="table" width="100%" id="dynamic_field">
      <tr>
        <td>Inicio:</td>
        <td>
          <input name="inicio[]" id="inicio" type="text" value="" class="form-control data" />
        </td>
        <td>Término:</td>
        <td>
          <input name="termino[]" id="termino" type="text" value="" class="form-control data" />
        </td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <a id="adicionar" class="btn btn-success" title="Adicionar data de início e término"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle">+</i></a>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" id="btn_passo2" class="btn btn-primary next-step">Salvar</button>
</form>
```

coloquei tbm no jsfiddle para melhor compreensão 
https://jsfiddle.net/opeta/p4jbc49f/

desde já agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Comment: Se você clicar Ctrl + M verá que tem um recurso parecido com o JSFiddle aqui no site mesmo.

Comment: @opeta qual o problema?

Comment: Não seria melhor você utilizar um input do tipo date do HTML5? Pois ai já dispensaria quaisquer validações, já que ele já limitaria o valor do campo a somente datas válidas.

Comment: Depende. Se você quer uma validação mais customizada aconselho usar o jQuery Validate. Caso não queira uma validação personalizada pode utilizar o tipo date do html5 mesmo, so adiciona o atributo required. Ex: https://jsfiddle.net/p4jbc49f/1/

Comment: @Newtech o problema é que ele valida só o primeiro campo quando adiciono ele não valida. eu estou usando o jquery validate.

Comment: Marque a sua resposta como a certa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consegui a solução e venho aqui compartilhar para quem tiver um problema parecido conseguir resolver:

eu estava usando o jquery.validate.min.js passei a usar a versão completa jquery.validate.js dentro dela procurei por checkForm e substitui a função inteira por esta:

```
checkForm: function() {
        this.prepareForm();
        for ( var i = 0, elements = (this.currentElements = this.elements()); elements[i]; i++ ) {
            if (this.findByName( elements[i].name ).length != undefined && this.findByName( elements[i].name ).length > 1) {
                for (var cnt = 0; cnt < this.findByName( elements[i].name ).length; cnt++) {
                    this.check( this.findByName( elements[i].name )[cnt] );
                }
            } else {
                this.check( elements[i] );
            }
        }
        return this.valid();
    },
```

e substitui isso

```
var i = 1;
  $('a#adicionar').click(function() {
    i++;

    $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row' + i + '"><td>Inicio:</td><td><input name="inicio[]" id="inicio' + i + '" type="text" value="" class="form-control data" /></td><td>Término:</td><td><input name="termino[]" id="termino' + i + '"type="text" value="" class="form-control data" /></td><td><a name="remove" id="' + i + '" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove"><i class="fa fa-times-circle">-</i></a></td></tr>');
    $(".data").mask("99/99/9999");
    $("#inicio" + i + "").focus();

  });
```

por isso:

```
var i = 1;
  $('a#adicionar').click(function() {
    i++;

    $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row' + i + '"><td>Inicio:</td><td><input name="inicio[]" id="inicio' + i + '" type="text" value="" class="form-control data" /></td><td>Término:</td><td><input name="termino[]" id="termino' + i + '"type="text" value="" class="form-control data" /></td><td><a name="remove" id="' + i + '" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove"><i class="fa fa-times-circle">-</i></a></td></tr>');
    $(".data").mask("99/99/9999");
    $("#inicio" + i + "").focus();

$('[name^="inicio"], [name^="termino"]').each(function () {
            $(this).rules("add", {
                required: true,
                  messages: {
            required: "* Informe a data"
          }

            });


            });

  });
```

fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10783358/validating-array-file-input